# x264 Is giving this error: x264_encoder_open failed, are the input file parameters wrong?

Tags: h.264, x264

I'm having some trouble getting x264 to work. I'm using [x264 t_mod_New version r2970](https://github.com/jpsdr/x264/releases/tag/r2970).
x264 keeps giving this error though:

> x264 [error]: can't open file '0'
>
> x264 [error]: x264_encoder_open failed

Full output:

```
x264_x64.exe --ref=5 --deblock=1:-3:-3 --analyse=0x3:0x113 --trellis=2 --cqm=0 --deadzone=6 --no-fast-pskip --chroma-qp-offset=-3 --threads=21 --lookahead-threads=1 --nr=0 --no-dct-decimate --bframes=2 --b-pyramid=none --b-adapt=2 --b-bias=0 --direct=spatial --no-weightb --weightp=2 --keyint=46 --min-keyint=23 --scenecut=99 --rc-lookahead=40 --no-mbtree --crf=20.0000 --qcomp=0.60 --qpmin=0:0:0 --qpmax=50:50:50 --qpstep=2 --vbv-maxrate=20000 --vbv-bufsize=25000 --crf-max=0.0 --nal-hrd=none --ipratio=1.10 --pbratio=1.10 --aq-sensitivity=10.00 -o "Ep. 01 - The Boy in the Iceberg-[720p].mp4" "Ep. 01 - The Boy in the Iceberg-[720p].mkv"
    mp4 [info]: audio muxing feature is disabled.
    ffms [info]:
     Format    : matroska,webm
     Codec     : h264
     PixFmt    : yuv420p
     Framerate : 30000/1001
     Timebase  : 1000/1000000
     Duration  : 0:23:29
    ffms [info]: 960x720p 1:1 @ 30000/1001 fps (vfr)
    ffms [info]: color matrix: undef
    mp4 [info]: audio muxing feature is disabled.
    x264 [error]: can't open file '0'
    x264 [error]: x264_encoder_open failed
    
    mp4 [error]: failed to finish movie.
    x264 [info]: ended at Wed Jun 05 10:44:11 2019
    x264 [info]: encoding duration 433256:44:12
```